# RubyTest Not Outputting Test Results on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ruby-test

I am on Windows 7 Pro and trying to use RubyTest with Sublime Text 2.  I have it installed.  I am getting no output in the test results window.  If I run a test for example, I see the following in the console:

Running `bin/rspec spec\features\static_pages_spec.rb -l9`
reloading `/C/Users/jgriffin/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/RubyTest.last-run`

If I run this at the command line in a Dos Window it executes.
If I run this at the command line in a Git Bash window it does not.

I would prefer to run out of my Bash window.  I've tried running subl from the commandline in both Bash and DOS Command windows but result always seem to be the same.  No output at all.

I'm running with:

```
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Post some code, man? How you expect us to help you otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to modify the `User - RubyTest.sublime-settings` file to include the `bundle exec` prefix if you haven't already for it to work on Windows through Sublime. I had the same problem not too long ago. For example:

```
{
  "erb_verify_command": "bundle exec erb -xT - {file_name} | ruby -c",
  "ruby_verify_command": "bundle exec ruby -c {file_name}",

  "run_ruby_unit_command": "bundle exec ruby -Itest {relative_path}",
  "run_single_ruby_unit_command": "bundle exec ruby -Itest {relative_path} -n '{test_name}'",

  "run_cucumber_command": "bundle exec cucumber {relative_path}",
  "run_single_cucumber_command": "bundle exec cucumber {relative_path} -l{line_number}",

  "run_rspec_command": "bundle exec rspec {relative_path}",
  "run_single_rspec_command": "bundle exec rspec {relative_path} -l{line_number}",

  "ruby_unit_folder": "test",
  "ruby_cucumber_folder": "features",
  "ruby_rspec_folder": "spec",

  "ruby_use_scratch" : false,
  "save_on_run": false,
  "ignored_directories": [".git", "vendor", "tmp"]
}
```

Comment: I did check the file.  I am using RSpec and tried both bundle exec and bin/rspec.  Both actually work on the command line for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, no error in the debug console, no output in the actual console.

In my case I needed to run sublime text as administrator (sublime_text.exe > properties > compatibility > Run this program as administrator).

Then I re-ran the tests through sublime text and after about 10 seconds it finally output the test results.

I hope this helps.